# ORMLite working too slow on load

Tags: android, ormlite

I have 1500+ items of this class stored in database :

```
public class Task implements Parcelable{

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG, id = true)
    private long ActionId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String Text;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String actionText;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isUrgent;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isImportant;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isCompleted;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String description;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isDeleted;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, canBeNull = true, index = true)
    private Role role;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, canBeNull = true, index = true)
    private List list;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isWeekly;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String Date;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    Long ActionListId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long createdAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long updatedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long deletedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isNew;  
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long roleId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long WorkspaceId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int order;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String WeekDate;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Task) {
             Task task = (Task)o;
             if(task.getActionId() == this.getActionId())
                  return true;
             return false;
        } else return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name : " + Text;
    }
}
```

And this is the code for those two foreign classes:

```
public class Role implements Parcelable{

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG, id = true)
    long id;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    String date;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    String Text;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    String Color;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG) 
    long WorkspaceId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    int Momentum;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    boolean isDeleted;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    Long createdAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    Long editedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    Long deletedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    boolean isNew;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int year;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int month;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int day;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long UserId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String UserName;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int order;
}
public class List  {

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER, generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG)
    private long ActionListId = -1;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String Name;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG)
    private long WorkspaceId;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String day;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE, canBeNull = true)
    private int[] date;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean parkingLot;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long CreatedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long EditedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_OBJ)
    private Long DeletedAt;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean IsDeleted;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
    private boolean isNew;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int taskCount;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    private int Order;
}
```

**Note:** I've already read this posts : [ORMLite poor performance on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206408/ormlite-poor-performance-on-android), this : [Ormlite DAO in android getting really slow when querying more than few thousand results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811466/ormlite-dao-in-android-getting-really-slow-when-querying-more-than-few-thousand), [How can I improve this method of loading objects with ORMLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769335/how-can-i-improve-this-method-of-loading-objects-with-ormlite-on-android)
And also i've read this : [ORMLite's createOrUpdate seems slow - what is normal speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761472/ormlites-createorupdate-seems-slow-what-is-normal-speed), and the thing is that for this 1500+ items creating is going fine, but this query is working too slow :

```
      try {
            dao = (TaskDao) DatabaseSingleton.getDAO(Task.class);
            QueryBuilder<Task, Integer> qB = dao.queryBuilder();
            qB.where().eq("WorkspaceId", workspaceId).and().eq("isDeleted", false);
            CloseableIterator<Task> iterator = dao.iterator(qB.prepare());
             try {
                 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                     Task item  = iterator.next();
                     ActionDto outputItem = new ActionDto(item);
                     list.add(outputItem);
                 }
             } finally {
                 iterator.close();
             }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So iterator doesn't help here

**Another note** : i've read about slow annotations and that it was fixed in Gingerbread, so i want to tell which devices i'm using :

1. Samsung GT-S5660 Galaxy Gio with 2.3.3 API
2. GenyMotion Nexus 5 emulator 4.4.2
3. Nexus 7 with 4.1.2 API

And it's working slow for all of them, I thought it can be somehow related to big amount of LONG_OBJECT in my classes, and the amount of fields in each one, but it's really take so much time to load 1500+ items(**It goes for 10+ seconds**)

***And also i don't really want to change ORM, because ORMLite worked just fine for me except for this case***

**Edit:** As there was replied in comments, i have to say that just `qB.query()` is taking almoust the same amount of time as `iterator` loop

Comment: Nik, did you locate where most time is spent (inside loop or while preparing iterator)?

Comment: I can surely say that if i just use "qB.query()" it would be that much time, i'll add it into edit